# Exceptions to Filesmatch htaccess rule?

Tags: .htaccess

Gidday

I've currently got js files set up as must-revalidate, to overcome mobile networks caching old versions when I do updates.

```
<FilesMatch ".(js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=608000"
Header set Cache-Control "must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

I have some .js files that I never change, so I was wondering how to go about making an exception for these files?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another `FilesMatch` section for those specific files:

```
<FilesMatch "\.js$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=608000"
Header set Cache-Control "must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

# CACHED FOREVER
<FilesMatch "(file1|file2)\.js$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT"
Header unset Last-Modified
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. Would I have to have htaccess files on each dir that the files are in, or would one htaccess in the public_html dir cover the CACHED FOREVER files for the whole site?